# C++ creating lambda from other constexpr lambdas executed in order can't be constexpr

Tags: c++, lambda, tuples, constexpr

Let's say I want to create a lambda that executes some other lambdas in order like this:

```
constexpr auto some_func{[]() {
  // do something
}};

constexpr auto some_other_func{[]() {
  // do something else
}};

constexpr auto funcs_tuple = std::tuple(some_func, some_other_func);
constexpr auto combined_funcs = do_funcs(funcs_tuple);

combined_funcs();
```

I have implemented the `do_funcs` function as:

```
template <std::size_t Idx = 0, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto do_funcs(const Tuple& tup) {
  return [&]() {
    if constexpr (Idx < std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>) {
      const auto f = std::get<Idx>(tup);
      f();
      do_funcs<Idx + 1>(tup)();
    }
  };
}
```

which just executes the functions in the tuple in order. However the resulting variable `combined_funcs` can't be declared constexpr because the reference to `funcs_tuple` in the call to `do_funcs` is not a constant expression.

I am trying the code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sefrvo) with clang(trunk) and get

> `error: constexpr variable 'combined_funcs' must be initialized by a constant expression`

> `note: reference to 'funcs_tuple' is not a constant expression`

Why is this not considered a constant expression? Is there a way that I can make it constexpr?

After some trial and error I have found that instead of capturing the tuple by reference in the returned lambda from `do_funcs` but rather capturing by value the resulting lambda can indeed be declared constexpr, but I really do not want to create a copy of the tuple for each recursive call to `do_funcs`.

```
constexpr auto do_funcs(const Tuple& tup) {
  // capture by value instead of reference
  //      |
  //      v
  return [=]() { ...
```

I would also like to make a helper function that takes a parameter pack of lambdas and dispatches it as a tuple to the `do_funcs` function like this:

```
template <typename... Funcs>
constexpr auto make_do_funcs(Funcs&&... fs) {
  const auto funcs = std::tuple(std::forward<Funcs>(fs)...);
  return do_funcs(funcs);
}
```

The reason I am using tuples instead of another method like this:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Funcs>
constexpr auto do_funcs(Func&& f, Funcs&&... fs) {
  return [f = std::forward<Func>(f), ... fs = std::forward<Funcs>(fs)] {
    f();
    if constexpr (sizeof...(fs) > 0) {
      do_funcs(fs...);
    }
  };
}
```

is because "perfect capture" is a C++20 feature and requires a workaround with tuples for C++17.

For further reference I am trying to make a utility "parser" for my combination parser library which executes some other parsers to create a more complex parser when needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why can't `combined_funcs` be declared `constexpr`? Do you get an error? Also, don't you mean `combined_funcs();` instead of `do_funcs();`?

Comment: @cigien yes, I get "error: constexpr variable 'combined_funcs' must be initialized by a constant expression, note: reference to 'funcs_tuple' is not a constant expression" using clang(trunk) on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sefrvo)

Comment: Ok. Add that error to the question. The link is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `funcs_tuple` `static`. Because it is `constexpr`, this shouldn't change really change anything about how your code functions, since all calls to whatever function this is should always arrive at the same value of `funcs_tuple`. (The differences would be if you were taking the address of it for some reason, I guess.) However, it *does* make references to `funcs_tuple` `constexpr`, because now there is one object represented by the `constexpr` variable and not one per invocation of the function. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:20,endLineNumber:24,positionColumn:20,positionLineNumber:24,selectionStartColumn:20,selectionStartLineNumber:24,startColumn:20,startLineNumber:24),source:%27%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cstd::size_t+Idx+%3D+0,+typename+Tuple%3E%0Aconstexpr+auto+do_funcs(const+Tuple%26+tup)+%7B%0A++return+%5B%26%5D()+%7B%0A++++if+constexpr+(Idx+%3C+std::tuple_size_v%3CTuple%3E)+%7B%0A++++++const+auto+f+%3D+std::get%3CIdx%3E(tup)%3B%0A++++++f()%3B%0A++++++do_funcs%3CIdx+%2B+1%3E(tup)()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++constexpr+auto+some_func%7B%5B%5D()+%7B%0A++++//+do+something%0A++%7D%7D%3B%0A%0A++constexpr+auto+some_other_func%7B%5B%5D()+%7B%0A++++//+do+something+else%0A++%7D%7D%3B%0A%0A++constexpr+static+auto+funcs_tuple+%3D+std::tuple(some_func,+some_other_func)%3B%0A++constexpr+auto+combined_funcs+%3D+do_funcs(funcs_tuple)%3B%0A%0A++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.658935879945446,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:trunk)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.41298686730288,l:%274%27,m:57.42811501597445,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:42.57188498402555,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.34106412005458,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Note that this doesn't work for a `constexpr` function. Thankfully, if the enclosing function is `constexpr`, the variables don't need to be. That is, you can do both/either

```
void func() { // func not constexpr
    static constexpr auto funcs_tuple = ...;
    constexpr auto combined_funcs = do_funcs(funcs_tuple);
}
```

or

```
// like in the question
template <typename... Funcs>
constexpr auto make_do_funcs(Funcs&&... fs) {
    // funcs not constexpr or static; make_do_funcs still constexpr
    const auto funcs = std::tuple(std::forward<Funcs>(fs)...);
    return do_funcs(funcs)(); // or whatever
    // note: you CANNOT return do_funcs(funcs), because that would be a dangling reference
    // your original make_do_funcs is simply broken
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far. Sorry for nitpicking but the only issue I see with this solution is you can't have a static variable in a constexpr function so if I want to make a constexpr helper function, say `make_do_funcs`  that takes a parameter pack of `Funcs` and creates a tuple from that and dispatches it to `do_funcs` I can't use this solution. I will add this requirement to the question.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand what you are saying. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/nevGnf) is ideally what I want to accomplish. Are you suggesting I make the `make_do_funcs` non-constexpr? Edit: sorry I posted the wrong link

Comment: @RikusHoney Sorry, I ran into that too, made a comment, realized it didn't work, deleted it, and now I just realized that I was right and your code is wrong. `make_do_funcs` returns a dangling reference. `funcs` is gone once `make_do_funcs` returns. It's not making the reference to `funcs` that is making it not a constant expression. It's that it's dangling if you put it in the return value. It's broken and wouldn't work whether or not it's `constexpr`. You need a copy in that one, I think.

Comment: I am still going to use my answer as it is what I ultimately want to achieve, but yours actually answers the question asked. Thanks for all the effort.

Answer (score 2):

What about a simply `std::apply()` (that folds over comma operator) as follows ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
 {
   auto some_func_1{[]() { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; }};
   auto some_func_2{[]() { std::cout << "2" << std::endl; }};

   auto funcs_tuple = std::tuple{some_func_1, some_func_2};

   auto do_funcs
      = [](auto const & tpl)
         { std::apply([](auto ... fn){ (fn(), ...); }, tpl); };

   do_funcs(funcs_tuple);
 }
```

You can see that you get printed `1` and `2`

Removing `std::cout`s (no `constexpr` compatible) and adding some `constexpr`, you have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
 {
   constexpr auto some_func_1{[]() { }};
   constexpr auto some_func_2{[]() { }};

   constexpr auto funcs_tuple = std::tuple{some_func_1, some_func_2};

   constexpr auto do_funcs
      = [](auto const & tpl)
       { std::apply([](auto ... fn){ (fn(), ...); }, tpl); };

   do_funcs(funcs_tuple);
 }
```

Comment: I am making a combination parser library and need some way of combining parsers to create a new parser that runs the given parsers in order, creating a more complex parser. I am going to have to write a bunch of parsers that combine other parsers or even combining parsers that are a combination of other parsers itself, so I want to reduce doing that to a simple function call.

Answer (score 0):

I have resulted to using my own helper struct to act as a lambda.

```
template <typename... Funcs>
struct do_funcs {
  constexpr do_funcs(Funcs... fs) : funcs{fs...} {}

  void operator()() const {
    do_rest();
  }

  template <std::size_t Idx = 0>
  void do_rest() const {
    if constexpr (Idx < sizeof...(Funcs)) {
      const auto f = std::get<Idx>(funcs);
      f();
      do_rest<Idx + 1>();
    }
  }

  const std::tuple<Funcs...> funcs;
};
```

which allows the example given in the question to be constexpr.

Comment: Is this solution better than the one in the question? This one seems to be making a copy of the tuple as well.

Comment: The problem with the solution in the question is that the lambda makes a copy of the tuple *every time* it is called recursively while this one just makes it once and then it is kept in the struct for the duration of the recursive calls.

Comment: Please see the link [here](https://cppinsights.io/s/a46c1aaa) which shows that for my initial solution each call with a different index to `do_funcs` it creates a new specialization of the lambda with a new copy of the tuple. [Here](https://cppinsights.io/s/e55ad187) is my new solution which shows it creates only a single copy.